# Making a .mp3 file downloadble

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a project that uploads audio and video files. I have no problem with the upload part. My challenge now is how to prevent streaming of the MP3 files
The files are uploaded on a folder and the path to the file is stored in MySQL DB.
Below is my download code.

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$categ="all";
$categ=$_GET['categ'];
if($categ=="all"){
$q="select * from upload_data";
}
else{
$q="select * from upload_data where CATEGORY='$categ'";
}
$result=mysql_query($q);
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "
 <tr>
<td width='1%'>".$rs['FILE_ID']."</td>
<td width='20%'>".$rs['FILE_NAME']." 
<br/>".$rs['FILE_SIZE']." KB
<br/><a href='".$rs['PATH']."'><button class='btn btn-primary'>Download<i class='icon-download-alt icon-white'></button></a></td>";
}
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can MP3's be included as a link in `<a></a>` tags to make them downloadable, similar to files?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Lewis — They are files.

Comment: My bad, I meant similar to PDFs and .DOCs rather than files as a whole. I know MP3 is considered multimieda and as such, the browser tries to stream rather than download - @OnwuBishopGideon anyways, they describe a method of how to do it here http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=27872

Comment: What @Quentin said. If you accept any user-supplied data and assemble a string that is used in a SQL query, your database **will** be hacked: all data retrieved, deleted or changed.

Comment: Set header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.mp3"`. You can add attribute `download` on your `<a>` too. Also, as others pointed out - get rid of that awful SQL injection you've got there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your observations so far. I have tried using content-disposition but it downloads the page instead.

Comment: @OnwuBishopGideon: You need to set it in document residing in `$rs['PATH']`, not the above code. Or you can use `download` attribute on `<a>`, as I've mentioned above (won't work on all browsers).

Answer (score -2):

You should probably analyze request headers and block those requests that contain 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked'

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I was able to solve it by adding this line of code to my .htaccess                                                                               <FilesMatch "\.(mp3|MP3)">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>